# Nuxt, how to include babel plugins

Tags: webpack, babeljs, nuxt.js

I have searched here and there as well read the documentation.

I would like to import
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining

in my nuxt.config.js
I tried

```
 build: {
    transpile: [/^element-ui/],
    babel: {
      presets () {
        return [
          ['@nuxt/babel-preset-app'],
          ['@babel/preset-env'],
        ];
      },
    },
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'],
  },
```

This error appeared

> WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. - configuration.plugins[2] should be one of these: object { apply, … } | function -> Plugin of type object or instanceof Function Details: * configuration.plugins[2] should be an object. -> Plugin instance * configuration.plugins[2] should be an instance of function -> Function acting as plugin

It doesn't seem to work.
I tried manually importing the package, but another error appeared

Comment: This is mainly a syntax issue on how to write it properly, depending of à version. Meanwhile, you don't need to import optional chaining, it is already available in your code. Did you tried it in your files?

Comment: I really think optional chaining is there though.....
since I use typescript, but I have problem of when trying to import pdfjs.

I was thinking since pdfjs is not on my scope, the compilation is failing thus the problem.

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/13200

Btw my nuxt version is 2.4.16

Comment: Wait, what is the actual question so?

Comment: the question still the same, how should I state babel build plugin in the config, since the error i had was about invalid schema not duplication or something